# How can I know whether ram is damaged?

Tags: memory, motherboard

I recently bought a Kingston ram from Amazon.com (I live in india) which has specification

```
Memory:4 GB
Speed-1333 MHz
```

When I place it in the RAM slot (tried along with older ram, and alone) the motherboard beeps on starting the PC and no display is shown.

Does this beeping indicates that my new RAM is faulty, because when I only use the old RAM my PC works fine?

Comment: We cannot tell from the information given. It may simply be incompatible. Did you check your motherboard manufacturer's compatibility list?

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes,I saw my motherboard specifications before buying the RAM and the RAM I bought should be compatible with the motherboard.

Comment: What more information is required?

Comment: part-numbers for starters

Comment: the part number is :KVR13N9S8H/4

Comment: *All* part numbers

Comment: What model is your motherboad? What kind of beeping does your motherboard produce (Short beeps, long beeps, or a combination of the two)?

Comment: @MrPublic The model of my motherboard is Foxconn motherboard 2A8C.The beeps are long.

Comment: @Yorik which other part number are you asking,I gave the part number which is written on RAM.